# How to set condition for a class in a <div> in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the div using d-none in bootstrap when the post.title is empty. I have tried so far and the card-body is still showing. There's no text but I don't want it to show at all. I am new to web dev in general so I really don't know how to achieve this. I am not sure my syntax is correct either. Any tips?

```
<div class = {${post.title} == '' ? "d-none" : "d-inline"}>
    <div class="card-body override-bs">
         ${post.title}
                                       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=`${post.title === '' ? "d-none" : "d-inline"}`>
   <div class="card-body override-bs">
     `${post.title}`                                 
   </div>
</div>
```

Here I am using Template literals and ternary operator.
Please have a look to both link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bootstrap:

```js
function hide(){
  document.getElementById("div").setAttribute("hide","true");
}
function show(){
  document.getElementById("div").setAttribute("hide","false");
}
```

```css
[hide="true"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div hide="true" id="div"><button onclick="hide();">X</button><p>So you want to hide a div? Bootstrap not needed! :)<p><img src="https://turtleonafencepostsite.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/fullsizerender.jpg?w=648" alt="Why Turtle on a Fence Post? – Turtle on a Fence Post"/></div>
<button onclick="show();">Show it</button>
```